# GRASS - add on problem

Tags: grass-gis, installation

I can't install the addon in GRASS 6.4.3 to my Linux mint. I've already installed the SVN and then it says:

```
GRASS 6.4.3 (fabian_idrisi):~ > g.extension r.fuzzy

Fetching  from GRASS-Addons SVN (be patient)...
A    r.fuzzy/local_proto.h
A    r.fuzzy/shape.png
A    r.fuzzy/main.c
A    r.fuzzy/boundary.png
A    r.fuzzy/description.html
A    r.fuzzy/fuzzy.c
A    r.fuzzy/Makefile
A    r.fuzzy/set.png
 U   r.fuzzy
Checked out revision 60053.
Compiling ...
Makefile:13: /usr/lib/grass64/include/Make/Module.make: No such file or directory 
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/grass64/include/Make/Module.make'.  Stop.
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
```

I try to locate that directory but my usr/lib/grass64/ folder only contains scripts, bin, driver, lib, locale ect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install the "grass-dev" package?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this going to directory that has the module:

```
cd /home/(personal)/grass-7.0.svn/raster/r.stream.order
```

as root, I type:

```
make MODULE_TOPDIR=/home/(myhome)/grass-7.0.svn/
make MODULE_TOPDIR=/home/(myhome)/grass-7.0.svn/ install
```

More information you can find [here](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install#Addons).